# Can I use LXC library in my c program?

Tags: c, lxc, programming, api

Currently, I am designing a c program that will create multiple container and put different applications into them separately to achieve isolation. Is it possible to leverage LXC library to it? I found the programming example on the [web site of LXC](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/documentation/), but I cannot find how I can include set up the library into my current system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu, `lxc-dev` contains the header files, so it's the starting point for writing code using the LXC libraries. Typically for Ubuntu, `foo` provides stuff that end-users expect, and `foo-dev` provides what developers need.